# Calculation of cardano tx fee

Tags: blockchain, cardano

I am trying to parsing the cardano tx, here is scenario 
I fetched the block data using the rosetta server.Block have all the transaction which are belong to that tx.
Now I want check the fee of tx so I was looking into the tx json but could not found any useful details ..
Can someone help me on it?
It would be good if you can share the doc related to block data structure.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out Bitquery Cardano Explorer https://explorer.bitquery.io/cardano/transactions  If you are comfortable with graphQL, you can write your own queries in the IDE https://ide.bitquery.io/.
[image]